# How can I retrieve all items from the paginated result of a DynamoDBMapper query()?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query DynamoDB with help of [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html#JavaORMDynamoDBMapper) in Java with both hashKey and rangeKey. But I am not getting all results, it returns only some part of it. My code looks like:

```
queryDynamoDb() {
  Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString())
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS("0"));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression(
            new AttributeValue().withS(prefKey));

    queryExpression.setRangeKeyCondition(rangeKeyCondition);

    List<MyObj> myobjs = mapper.query(MyObj.class, queryExpression);
    return myobjs;
}
```

`MyObj` is properly annotated with DynamoDB annotations. So I am able to save the objects, but retrieval returns a partial result only.

The documentation of *query* within [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html#JavaORMDynamoDBMapper) says:

> The query method returns the "lazy-loaded" collection. That is, initially it returns only one page of results. It makes a service call for the next page when needed.

Now the question is, how to tell the mapper to make a service call or that a page is needed, so it loads all pages (effectively all entries)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Java code snippet within the [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) documentation for the [DynamoDBMapper Class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html#JavaORMDynamoDBMapper) is a bit unfortunate here (though technologically correct), the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) API documentation for [Class DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html) is (naturally) more precise in this regard, see method [query()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#query%28java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression%29):

```
public <T> PaginatedQueryList<T> query(Class<T> clazz,
                                       DynamoDBQueryExpression queryExpression)
```

So the returned type is actually a [Class PaginatedQueryList](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/PaginatedQueryList.html):

> Implementation of the List interface that represents the results from
>   a query in AWS DynamoDB. **Paginated results are loaded on demand** when
>   the user executes an operation that requires them. **Some operations,
>   such as size(), must fetch the entire list**, but results are lazily
>   fetched page by page when possible. *[emphasize mine]*

That is, you really do not need to explicitly load anything during normal usage, insofar it is implicitly taken care of by the lazy-loading implementation of `PaginatedQueryList<T>`; however, if so desired for whatever reason, you can trigger it by operations requiring access to the entire collection, with the explicitly mentioned [size()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/PaginatedList.html#size%28%29) method being one of them apparently.

Comment: Open, I agree with your answer, Looks like I am into the same issue. Question is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495145/issue-with-caching-and-dynamo-db-combination

Answer (score 1):

as a reference to the approved answer, yes it's possible to load all results by calling `size()` or `loadAllResults()` itself. check the screenshots below.

Another alternative would be changing the PaginationLoadingStrategy as `EAGER_LOADING` on `DynamoDBMapperConfig` before the call.

example:

```
final DynamoDBMapperConfig config = DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder()
        .withTableNameOverride(new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride("tableName"))
        .withPaginationLoadingStrategy(DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy.EAGER_LOADING)
        .build();
// all results
List<TableEntity> tableEntity = dynamoDBMapper.scan(TableEntity.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression(), config);
```

[image: PaginatedList.size()]

[image: PaginatedList.loadAllResults()]

I know it's an old question but I end up here when I look for eager loading